# Sorting an ICollection descending by average including nullable values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-ctp5

Given the following code:

```
class Book {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

class Review {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? Overall { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

And assuming I have a list of every book in the database:

```
var books; // List<Book>
```

I would like to show the user the books ordered by the average review.  Ideally, the list of books would have the highest average review at the top and sort descending.  Given I have the overall rating in Review as a null-able integer, some books will not have reviews, let alone an overall score.  I'm having difficulty sorting this data, I've tried seemingly every combination of:

```
books.OrderByDescending(b => b.Reviews.Average(a => a.Overall));
```

Is it possible to sort my list without creating a second list to get something like:

- Book A (4.5/5)
- Book B (4.3/5)
- Book C (3.9/5)
- Book D (3.5/5)
- Book E (-/5)
- Book F (-/5)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you TheCodeKing for point me in the right direction.  Here is what fixed the problem:

```
books.OrderByDescending(b => b.Reviews.Count() == 0 ? 0 : b.Reviews.Average(r => r.Overall ?? 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this:

```
books.OrderByDescending(b => 
                  (b.Reviews == null) ? 0:b.Reviews.Average(r => r.Overall??0));
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, it throws an invalid operation exception "sequence contains no elements".  Thanks though.

Comment: @jon - i think you need to verify and more closely at the error message. Do the books have reviews?

Comment: @Ahmad, the original question was how do I sort a list of books by average review given the fact that some books have no reviews?

Comment: I interpreted that as the null on your nullable Overall field. I'll update.